# When is it safe to use PHP Get requests

Tags: php, request

I am creating a web application that has a user area. I would like to divert all errors to one page called errors.php with a parameter string like this:

```
header("Location:error.php?message=This is a particular error.");
```

I read a lot about **not** using GET requests for security reasons but does that apply if the data is not sensitive? Put another way, does the use of GET requests for non-sensitive data open up vulnerabilities in other areas of the site? Or is it safe to say GET can be used without limitations when the data is not secure data (passwords, usernames, emails, etc.).

Comment: Read a google policy : http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.gr/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html

Answer (score 1):

Using GET is less secure when you want to pass sensitive information. For example - passing a password.

Using GET to pass an identifier, such as product ID for example, is perfectly OK.

Don't pass with GET any sensitive information. Passing an error description, as long as you don't revel sensitive information inside of it, is OK.

Any way, always filter the data on the server side.

Think on the example:
error.php?message=alert(1)

If someone will send a link with this URL, the JS script will execute, unless you will filter it. Alert is no dangures, but this way can be used for a lot of malicious actions.

Any way, I believe that you better set a list of errors with error codes, and pass the error code insted of a full description string of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you display `$_GET['message']` in `error.php` you have a potential [XSS vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you don't escape it with something like `htmlspecialchars`.

You'd also want to `urlencode()` your message parameter, in case it contains special characters like `#` that'd break stuff.